# Using reduce(into:_:) to filter adjacent equal elements

Tags: arrays, swift, fold

The Swift Standard Library API specifies that Array has a method [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce) that returns the result of combining the elements of the sequence using the given closure.

The API docs mention that "you can use this method on an array of integers to filter adjacent equal entries". Can someone provide an example of how this would be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could eliminate runs of equal numbers like this:

```
let numbers = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3]
let filtered = numbers.reduce(into: [Int]()) { newArray, number in
    if newArray.last != number { newArray.append(number) }
}

print(filtered)
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3]

Comment: Aha, it's kind of like putting it into a Set and then back into an array.